# Adjust the text for the smaller screens

Tags: html, css, wordpress, hover, responsive

Hy, I tried to adjust the text for smaller screens by using @media screen and (min-width: 767px) but it messed up everything, I put it in the  tag

Please find the code below, help is appreciated, coming fine for desktop but not for small devices.

I have this code added in HTML editor in wordpress.

Link of website: beta.edgerope.com, there is text at the start of the page, in a background video. "Services, Training and Shop"

```html
<style>




.image{
   
  height: 800px;
  width:  100%;
 display:flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: Times New Roman;
   //display: grid;
  place-content:center;
  justify-content:middle;
  color: white;
  font-size:30px;
  background-color: #;
    background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;

}

.training{
    
    padding-top: 500px;
  padding-right:430px;
  padding-left: 20px;


}
  .shop{
     
     padding-top: 500px;
     padding-left: 50px; 
  }
  
  .services{
      
      padding-top: 500px;
      padding-right:450px;
  }
 
.image>div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  
}

.image>div img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0;
 z-index: 0;
 display: inline-block;
}

.image>div span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image>div span:hover+img {
  opacity: 1;
   //cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}



</style>

<div class="image">
   
    
    <div class="services">
    
      <span onclick="window.location=''">Services</span>
 
    <img src="https://www.petzl.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0686800000D6sSCAAZ"> 
   
    </div>
    
    
  <div class="training">
      
      <span  onclick="window.location='beta.edgerope.com/courses'">Training</span>

    
    <img src="https://beta.edgerope.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/1-1-1536x864.jpg"> </div>
    
  <div class="shop">
     <span onclick="window.location='beta.edgerope.com/shop'">Shop</span>
     
     
    <img src="https://www.petzl.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0686800000D6sSCAAZ"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly, in your `.image` you have `justify-content` two times. `justify-content` doesn't have an attribute called `middle`, you probably meant `center`.  Second thing, you can't comment out stuff with `//` instead you have to use `/* comment */` Now to your main problem: `@media screen and (min-width: 767px)` is used if the screen is bigger or equal to 767px, not if it's smaller. It would be helpful to have to see what you tried so far with the media query and what exactly messed it up and how it should look like instead.

Comment: Yes, but **justify-content** dont have any effect cause **display: flex** and **justify: space-evenly** is used, for comments **//** working for me, but thanks for your suggestions. For **@media screen** , I tried to put in start of <style> and end the brackets before end tag. Cause for big screens for e.g: LCD, Laptops it is working fine so tried for smaller screens only (ONLY FOR TABLET, DONT NEED FOR MOBILE FOR NOW). Thanks, I will try again with more effort. Thanks –

Comment: The video is playing fine in bg of main page, I have used **@media screen and (min-width: 767px)** cause I want to show in big screens like LCD, Laptops and Tablet. Please find link of website to be more specific [link](https://beta.edgerope.com) only issue is that all the text which is appearing on LCD/ Laptop will not appear in tablet rather the middle/center text of "TRAINING" appears. Thanks

Comment: It's not very clean to wrap all CSS in a media query and write different CSS for a bunch of screen sizes. Instead, you should write a "default" style and if some attributes have to change on a specific screen size, you're overriding them in the media queries. "comments // working for me" just because the line maybe gets greyed out in your IDS doesn't mean that they are actually working. If you open the website up, you can see the attributes in your inspector. However, I would recommend you to rewrite your code to have a container box, therein a img tag and another container containing the ...

Comment: ... three links, to change the actual image, use the `mouseover` event of javascript. If a link is hovered, change the img source (or replace the hole tag) in your container. How does this solve your main problem: you can add `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-evenly` to your subcontainer and the three categories should now be automatically pushed together when the screen size is shrinking and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you so much, everything looks fine for now, by using diff media queries, will definitely check your suggestion in case there is issue, thanks